# Questioning Stability

Tags: statistical-mechanics, atomic-physics, stability

Today in class my professor was teaching about Einstein's coefficients  and in the talk of excited states in spontaneous emission, he was explaining about meta stability of an atom. This made me question, "why stability". Yes of course that is when a system has the least entropy and minimises its energy loss. But I cannot understand why the should a system be stable. What is the real meaning of stability?And why do objects ,when left free, tend to a state or position were they are stable all the time?

Comment: *"But I cannot understand why the should a system be stable."* It comes from observation. There are systems that stable, there are systems that are not stable. There is no universal law that says all systems have to be stable. Not all real systems tend to stable state. Globular clusters and galaxies evolve for a long time with no stable state in sight. Some elements are radioactive, they do not tend to stable state but disintegrate into other elements. But some systems do tend to be stable, like a marble in a bowl.

Comment: @JánLalinský, that comment would actually make a nice answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search I think I finally got the answer.
The stability somehow happens to be a low frequency of state changes. For a given energy distribution, you will get changes when the values are often over the limits leading to change each state.

However, these limits increase by accumulation as a simple Markov chain may show ( objects stay more time in big holes ). And when the limits increase by this mechanism, the occurences of energy levels needed for states changes become fewer. The system converges to a not absolute local minima ... which may be disturbed by  a quantum rare high level, and then starting the convergence to another minima.

The fields prize winner, Cedric Vilanni has written a paper regarding this:"Entropy production and hypocoercivity"
that clearly shows that elements hadn't to know anything leading to the measure of the emergent stability.

Link: http://cedricvillani.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/B05.IHP_.pdf

(Please do let me know what you think about this)

Answer (score 3):

Because physical systems tend towards a situation in which their potential energy is minimised.

[image]

C is obviously the most stable point here, and another physical example is the shape of a soap bubble which minimises it's surface area and potential energy.

[image]

Comment: Yes I am aware that it's a state where it minimises its energy loss, but why does it always tend to that state. Of course for you and I we are perfectly aware that minimising energy loss is good and beneficial for the human system, but how is a particle like an atom or an electron aware of that fact and tends towards stability.

Comment: Take the opposite view, what would any system look like ,or even the universe, if it did not have this constraint on it?. It's the 2nd law of thermodynamics. What would happen if electrons never fell to their ground state? It would break every physical law we have, conservation of energy included. A universe without stability would not be amenable to life.  An electron or any other particle is only following the rules of nature, it's just a fact that we verify by experiment  every day.  I personally would not read any more into it than that.

Comment: So coming back to lasers and spontaneous emissions( the background of the question), is the meta-physical stability of the electrons or atoms acting as a check on the system to keep it stable, or at least bring it back to equilibrium?

Comment: The only thing ultimately   acting as a check on any system is us. Whether there is a reason beyond the fact that basic particles follow the rules  that we know by experiment & tests, is more philosophy than physics, I am afraid to say. Without meaning offence to you, I cannot tell why lots of **people** do the things they do, so electrons and the rules of nature are far beyond me. I can quote you ( and you know them yourself) thermodynamic laws that say that systems will act in opposition to any change in stability, but not any deeper than that.

Comment: can you take a look at my answer and reflect your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the system is absolutely isolated,  there will be mechanisms for energy to leave the system.   And absolute isolation is impossible to achieve.   As long as there are pathways for energy to leave the system, and there always are, energy *will* leave the system, and the system will inch closer to a state of stability.   Sometimes the energy paths are very small and very slow so that the relaxation to equilibrium might take times longer than the age of the universe.  One might call such situations "absolute stability".

Comment: But why should it tend to become stable? Why does the particle(hypothetically lets assume its absolutely isolated) always go to that state where it conserves energy and becomes stable?

Comment: @NaveenBalaji -  Because once the excited state has emitted the photon, well, that is it. It doesn't mean there isn't some overlap integral back to the excited state, but without energy in the system it can't get there. (Note in, say, a gas, there is a well-defined probability distribution of atoms in the excited state, but for each one that emits a photon it then needs to be re-excited).

Comment: @JonCuster Let's say in a gas ,as you have mentioned, for each excited electron within an atom to come back to its ground state, a photon is emitted and the electron has to be re-excited to do the same process agin. The electrons(in a population of N ground state electrons )excited first are the ones that radiate energy and come back to their ground state the first. Let's assume a three state system. Here the electrons in the first excited state are relatively less stable than the ones in the ground state and the electrons in the second ES are less stable than the ones in the first ES...

Comment: ...hence the first ES electrons have some entropy associated with them and the second ES electrons, even more. Now, when the excited electrons start radiating and come back to GS, locally the gas is getting heated, the atom is becoming stable and the system is cooling down as its radiating heat from all the excited electrons from all the atoms of the gas. Thus, the system is heating at local points but cooling overall, thus decreasing the entropy and violating the 2nd law of thermodynamics.